# Can't connect Kindle3, smartphone and now Samsung Note to Wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, wireless-router, kindle

I'm having some difficulties with my wireless connection. 
I have a modem Gigaset 201A and a wirelles router D-link524, and I can connect Two desktops running Vista and Windows7, and a LG and a Dell laptop running Win7. Since I bought my Kindle3 I could never connect it to the wireless, it always say

```
Wi-Fi network connection failed. Your kindle is unable to connect to the Wi-Fi network "Localnet". WOuld you like to enter the password again or manually set up this network?
```

I can connect the Kindle to other networks, like my parents and the university's.
Recently a friend tried to connect his smartphone and also couldn't, and today  I couldn't connect a Samsung laptop.

The smartphone and laptop just say it was unable to connect.

Also, when I run ipconfig /all from my desktop it says the router is at 168.196.1.5, but I cannot access it's settings page at this ip (I also have no idea how it ended in there, it used to be at 168.196.0.1).

Modem is at 168.196.1.1 as always.

I have already connected 2 desktops and 1 laptop at once, so I know the network supports at least 3 connections. Turning the laptop off, I still cannot connect.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modem.... an ADSL connection?  Cable Modem?  What model modem?  Does the modem have a router built into it (some ADSL modems do)?

Since your gateway device has apparently changed (and without your knowledge) maybe you should take your network setup completely apart, reduce it all to the defaults, and start again.  You know... use that Reset button on the back of the [unknown model] router and set it up all over again.

The fact that the router doesn't have a gateway address anymore, but the modem apparently does means that the modem is now acting like a gateway, and it is passing out the IP addresses for each device.

Don't forget.  As soon as you reset your router, set up wireless security.  For all we know, you could have left it unprotected, and a neighbor (or neighbor's kid) could have accessed and changed your router's settings.

Comment: Modem ADSL Gigaset 201A, connected to internet and router by cable. I don't know if this modem has a built in router. My network is secured by a WPA2 key.Router is D-link-524.

Comment: I'm a little scared to reset it all, because if something goes wrong, I just can't afford to be without any conection to the internet.

Comment: Almost all ADSL modems have router firmware, *BUT* are preset to only allow one device to be connected.  Which means your router needs to be set to take the internet connection from the modem, and then re-route it to a different internal IP address.  If you weren't the one who set up your router the first time, you might want to call that person to come and set it up now.

Comment: Ok, I think I'll follow your advice. Thank you for the reply.